# Find most recent entries before date criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble on figuring out how to find the most recent entry in a table <= to a specified date.

Example Table:

```
ENTRY_DATE  ID  PRICE
01/JAN/2010 1   1.2
01/JAN/2010 2   1.4
01/JAN/2010 3   2.6
02/JAN/2010 1   1.1
02/JAN/2010 2   1.5
02/JAN/2010 3   2.2
03/JAN/2010 1   1.0
03/JAN/2010 2   1.2
03/JAN/2010 3   2.4
04/JAN/2010 2   1.2
04/JAN/2010 3   2.8
05/JAN/2010 1   1.1
05/JAN/2010 3   2.9
```

I want to be able to say find me the most recent prices for all IDs on or before 05/01/2010. Now there isn't always necessarily a price update for every single ID on the same date, so with the above table I would want the following results:

```
ENTRY_DATE  ID  PRICE
04/JAN/2010 2   1.2
05/JAN/2010 1   1.1
05/JAN/2010 3   2.9
```

So it's returning the prices for IDs 1 and 3 because it found entries for 05/01/2010, and then it's finding the most recent non null value for ID 2 which is from 04/01/2010. I have seen some previous questions/examples for almost similar questions which use Coalesce but I can't get my head around how it works. I also saw some examples which use MAX, and I was running into trouble with it wanting every single column to be in the group by statement. Note: I am using Microsoft SQL Management Server rather than Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/878c4/15)

You can do it like below :

```
select t1.id, t1.entry_date, t1.price from TableName t1
    join (
        select id, max(entry_date) entry_date from TableName
        where ENTRY_DATE <= '05/01/2010'
        group by id
    ) as t2 
on t1.id=t2.id and t1.entry_date=t2.entry_date
```

In the derived table, the recent dates of each `ID` is selected and `JOINED` with the table by that recent date and the `ID`

Comment: Everyone's answer was valid and did work for me, but this was the one that I was able to shoehorn into my query the easiest. Although still very useful to learn other method, so thanks everyone.

Comment: It's great that your problem is sorted out. Don't forget to mark this answer as useful(upvote) also. Don't thank us, rather follow [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve what you want. One of which is by using analytic function such as `ROW_NUMBER()` to generate sequential number foreach `ID` based on latest `ENTRY_DATE`

```
SELECT  ENTRY_DATE,  ID,  PRICE
FROM
(
    SELECT  ENTRY_DATE,  ID,  PRICE,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ENTRY_DATE DESC)
    FROM    TableName
    WHERE   '20100105' <= ENTRY_DATE 
) a
WHERE   RN = 1
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/72528/1).

The query below will display `2` which is not included in the daterange

```
;WITH x AS
(
    SELECT  ENTRY_DATE,  ID,  PRICE,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ENTRY_DATE DESC)
    FROM    TableName
    WHERE   '20100105' <= ENTRY_DATE 
)
SELECT  ENTRY_DATE,  ID,  PRICE
FROM    x
WHERE   RN = 1
UNION
SELECT a.ENTRY_DATE,  a.ID,  a.PRICE
FROM 
(
    SELECT  ENTRY_DATE,  ID,  PRICE,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ENTRY_DATE DESC)
    FROM    TableName
) a
LEFT JOIN x ON a.ID = x.ID
WHERE   a.RN = 1
        AND x.ID IS NULL
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/72528/3).

Comment: In the SQL Fiddle demo, its only returning entries for IDs 1 and 3, but is not returning the most recent entry for ID 2? Edit: Nevermind, just saw the edit!

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/de008/2)

This should work:

```
create table #t(entry_date datetime,id int,price float)

insert into #t values
('01/JAN/2010', 1,   1.2),
('01/JAN/2010', 2,   1.4),
('01/JAN/2010', 3,   2.6),
('02/JAN/2010', 1,   1.1),
('02/JAN/2010', 2,   1.5),
('02/JAN/2010', 3,   2.2),
('03/JAN/2010', 1,   1.0),
('03/JAN/2010', 2,   1.2),
('03/JAN/2010', 3,   2.4),
('04/JAN/2010', 2,   1.2),
('04/JAN/2010', 3,   2.8),
('05/JAN/2010', 1,   1.1),
('05/JAN/2010', 3,   2.9)

;with cte as
(
 select *,
   ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by entry_date desc) as x
 from #t
 where entry_date <= '04/JAN/2010' /* -- here is your input param*/
)
select cast(entry_date as date), id, price from cte
where x=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as some answers but I started working on it before they were posted

```
declare @t table (entry_date datetime, id tinyint, price money);
insert into @t values
('01/JAN/2010', 1, 1.2),
('01/JAN/2010', 2, 1.4),
('01/JAN/2010', 3, 2.6),
('02/JAN/2010', 1, 1.1),
('02/JAN/2010', 2, 1.5),
('02/JAN/2010', 3, 2.2),
('03/JAN/2010', 1, 1.0),
('03/JAN/2010', 2, 1.2),
('03/JAN/2010', 3, 2.4),
('04/JAN/2010', 2, 1.2),
('04/JAN/2010', 3, 2.8),
('05/JAN/2010', 1, 1.1),
('05/JAN/2010', 3, 2.9);

declare @searchDate datetime = '05/01/2010';
select @searchDate as 'searchDate';

select cast(tt.entry_date as date) 'entry_date', tt.id, tt.price 
from ( select t.entry_date, t.id, t.price 
            , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t.id order by t.entry_date desc) as rn  
       from @t t
       where t.entry_date <=  @searchDate 
     ) tt 
where tt.rn = 1 
order by tt.id
```